# c++ STL cout source code

Tags: c++, cout

I want to see source code of STL `std::cout` function. I looked at iostream, but I've seen only  "extern cout". So, I guess that it's defined somewhere in the library.

I downloaded source code from  [official site](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html)

I extracted it and did:

```
sh@sh-R528-R728:~/desktop/stl$ grep -F * | grep "cout"
```

but I got nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Where is the source code?

Comment: I'm willing to bet the source code would burn your eyes.

Comment: may be, I just want to see how it works. I would to like to compare printf and cout inside.

Comment: `std::cout` is not a function, it's an object. That aside, try your luck with [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) in iostream.cpp.

Comment: `operator<<` is what you are probably interested in.  Search for that.

Comment: `std::cout` is also not part of the STL.

Comment: or probably you might be interested in looking out for ostream.

Comment: @shbk - Most of the source is templates that you can find in the headers. `std::cout` is just an object of type `ostream`. You will find all of that in `<ostream>` provided with your compiler.

Comment: Also note this from the SGI page: "Last updated: 8-June-00".

Comment: it's sad for me, but there is only one entry of cout in ostream file - in comments. I am confused. I feel that I only go around.

Comment: `std::cout` is not a function; it is an instance of `std::ostream`. It is not part of the SGI STL, but of the C++ Standard Library. This is why everybody calling [parts of] the Standard Library "the STL" is harmful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cout` is not part of the STL, so you won't find the source for `cout` in the STL source.

You probably want to look for the source for your C++ standard library, which was based on the STL, but also contains iostreams. Where that is depends on what platform you're using.

Comment: well, nice as I see here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ . The header of cout is ostream. I cannot find realization of  cout in ostream. Could you plz give a tip how to find it?  I sought word "cout" and I've founf it only in comments.

Comment: @shbk: Alan is referring to the fact that the C++ standard library and the STL are different things.  However, many many people call the C++ standard library "STL" since it originated as a copy of the STL Library.  The original STL library did not contain streams.

Comment: @shbk: cout should not be in ostream, it should be in iostream.  But as was said in the comments, cout is an object, not a function.  So finding cout isn't going to tell you how it works.  You need to find its class(ostream) and the functions of that class.

Comment: @MooingDuck: the C++ standard library did not originate as a *copy* of the STL; rather, it subsumed large parts of the STL (but not all of it, even in C++11).

Comment: it's nice. But in <iostream> I can find only this:               extern ostream cout;  ///< Linked to standard output

Comment: @shbk: **FORGET ABOUT COUT. IT IS NOT WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR. READ THE THINGS WE ARE SAYING.**

Comment: @Mooing it's not just that - the OP's link points to the SGI STL, which definitely doesn't include `cout`.

Answer (score 9):

If you happen to be using GCC, then `libstdc++` is your C++ library. Its sources can be found on [gcc.gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/). `cout` is defined on line 58 of [`src/c++98/globals_io.cc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/globals_io.cc?revision=184997&view=markup).

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` is not a function, it is a instance of `std::ostream` [(interface description)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/) that is tied to standard output.

If you are using gcc/libstdc++, have a blast browsing its [source code](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=cout;) online

Comment: Better: [gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=\bcout\b&sr=1](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=\bcout\b&sr=1)