# Why should we use "#include<iostream>" while we are using "using namespace std"?

Tags: c++

I have searched this question in Google. I found some related question in `stackoverflow.com` and `quora.com` but i am still not clear about this two topics. Everyone says that we use `#include<iostream>` for input/output operation. Now, we take input using `cin` and print output using `cout` that means this two should be defined in `#include<iostream>`. But without using `using namespace std`we still can't take any input nor can print something on console. So, my questions are-

1. Where is `cin` and `cout` actually declared and defined? Is it in `#include<iostream>`or in `namespace std`?
2. If in `#include<iostream>`why should we use `using namespace std`?
3. If in `namespace std` why should we use `#include<iostream`?

After reading some article on the web and watching some videos on YouTube, I'm assuming `cout` and `cin` is defined in `namespace std` and the `namespace std` doesn't make any sense alone because it is defined in `#include<iostream>`. That's why we need to use them both. (Just my thought let me know if I am right or not.)

The purpose of this question is to be clear about this two facts. If you can help it would be great.

Comment: [Don't use `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: 1. Both, 2. You shouldn't, 3. Because thats where `std::cout` and `std::cin` come from.

Comment: _But without using `using namespace std` we still can't take any input nor can print something on console._ **Wrong**. Use `std::cin`/`std::cout` instead.

Comment: The most help I can give would be to point you to [this list of books](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/2069064)

Comment: @Raindrop7 _"so you don't have to include all the content of the header:"_ Sure?? Or did you mean _use all the content_ (reading _include_ as `#include`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why should we use `#include <iostream>`

To bring the standard library's I/O functionality into our program.

> while we are using `using namespace std`?

This allows us to use that functionality without writing `std::` each time we do.

**This is unrelated to the previous step.** Writing only `using namespace std` does not bring I/O functionality into your program, and writing only `#include <iostream>` does not allow us to use that functionality without writing its components' names out in full (including the `std::` prefix).

- The `#include` directive determines what we can use;
- The `using namespace` declaration determines how we can use it.

---

Perfectly fine:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

Also valid:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

Not valid:

```
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

And neither is this:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

or this:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

Comment: I have assumed throughout that you have misunderstood what `using namespace std` means.

Comment: Well, I knew we use `using namespace std` to reduce our typing which is adding `std::` every time before we write something like `cout` or `cin`. I also knew that we use `namespace` to avoid naming collision. I just wanted to know the relation between `namespace` and the `header file` why we need them both.

Comment: @RubelHosen: Well if you know what `using namespace std` does then I cannot comprehend why you think `#include` is related.

Comment: `@Lightness Races in Orbit` Because I only know what `namespace` does, I only know what `header file` does. I don't know the relationship between them, I don't know why I need them both. I can't make use of `cout` without `std` and `iostream`. I don't know what is stopping me. i don't know if  `namespace` is a part of `iostream` and `cout` is defined in `std` nor I know if `iostream` is a part of `std` and `cout` is defined in `iostream`.

Comment: @RubelHosen: Sorry, if you understand what headers do and what `using namespace` does, you already know the two are unrelated. I'm not trying to be difficult - if I can't understand your misconception, I can't help any further to correct it.

Answer (score 4):

`cin` and `cout` are defined in the header `iostream` and in the namespace `std`. These concepts are orthogonal. `iostream` is a file name and `std` is a namespace used by the source code of that file.

As a way of keeping things organized, c++ provides namespaces. All of the standard library is defined within the namespace called `std`. Other libraries you might write or include may use their own namespace. For example, you might include a physics library in your project which wants to define the concept of algebraic vectors. By using it's own namespace (let's called if `physlib`) it can differentiate between it's `vector` (`physlib::vector`) and the standard `vector` (`std::vector`). Namespaces can also be nested to help organize large projects. For example, time keeping parts of the standard library are in `std::chrono` and file system related components are in `std::filesystem`.

The preferred way of using `cin` and `cout` is as following. :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The statement `using namespace std` is simply an instruction to look in the namespace `std` by default. It allows you to omit the `std::` part of using standard library components. It's generally regarded as [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to used `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 2):

`#include <iostrem>` tells the compiler to pull in the contents of the header `iostream`. That header provides, among other things, declarations of the objects `std::cin` and `std::cout`. So the basic "Hello, world" program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Similarly, if you want to use `std::vector`, you tell the compiler about it with `#include <vector>`. Same thing for the rest of the standard library: whatever it is that you want to use, find out which header declares it and `#include` that header.

`using namespace std;` doesn't define any names for you. It tells the compiler to pretend that any names that have been defined in the namespace `std` are also defined in the scope where `using namespace std;` occurs. So that means that instead of writing `std::cout` you can write `cout`, and the compiler will figure out that you meant `std::cout`. Unless, of course, you've written something yourself with the name `cout` (or any other name that's in `std` and declared in a header that you've `#include`d), in which case that using declaration makes the use of the name ambiguous. There is no good reason to write `using namespace std;`. Just use the right names for things: `std::cout` is clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Where is `cin` and `cout` actually declared and defined? Is it in `#include<iostream>` or in `namespace std`?

It's not *or*. `cin` and `cout` are declared in the `iostream` header file within the `namespace std`.

> 2. If in `#include< iostream>` why should we use `using namespace std`?

You shouldn't. Either fully qualify the global variables like `std::cin` or `std::cout`. There's a number of reasons why you shouldn't use `using namespace std;` (at least in header files).

> 3. If in `namespace std` why should we use `#include<iostream>?`

Because you need the declarations to compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

`iostream` is part of the standard library, here is what the "iostream.h" file would look like if you were to implement it yourself:

```
namespace std{
// code about cin
  extern ostream cin;
// code about cout
  extern ostream cout;
}
```

(see [c++ STL cout source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676336/c-stl-cout-source-code))

> Where is `cin` and `cout` actually declared and defined? Is it in `#include <iostream>` or in `namespace std`?

So `cin`/`cout` are declared and define in the standard library under the 
`namespace std`. This means that if you want to use it in your code you can do :

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

> If in `#include<iostream>` why should we use `using namespace std`?

You don't need `using namespace std`, you could call `std::cout` everywhere instead of cout, but you can see how this can make your code verbose and annoying to type.
`using namespace std` in your whole file is actually discouraged as it could have unintended effect, usually you could use only

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

where needed.

The reason the using is needed (or the need for explicitly writing `std:cout` , is imagine you have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace mycoolnamespace
{
  class foo { 
     public:
     foo& operator<< (const std::string& echo)
     {
         // do stuff
     }
  };


  foo cout; // created a variable called cout
}

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello"; 
 // ^^^^ compiler can't know if you meant to use std::cout or mycoolnamespace::cout here!

  // Potential fix:
  std::cout << "Hello"

}
```

> If in `namespace std` why should we use `#include<iostream>`?

By default not all function/classes from the standard library are included in your program, otherwise a simple "Hello world" program would give a lot of work to the compiler since it would need to parse all the existing classes/functions in the entire standard library. `#include<iostream>` tells the compiler that you need the functions/classes available in the standard library's `iostream` 'file'

Comment: It's not "iostream.h"